# Get key value based on value of another key in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have a case I keep coming across where I need to get just an object key - not the entire object - based on another key value in the same object, all from an array of objects.

So for example, if I have the following array of objects:

```
myArray = [
  {
    name: Person 1
    type: alpha
  },
  {
    name: Person 2
    type: beta
  },
  {
    name: Person 3
    type: gamma
  },
  {
    name: Person 4
    type: beta
  },
  {
    name: Person 5
    type: gamma
  },
];
```

So if I want to get just the name values for those objects with a type of 'beta', how would I do that? I prefer lodash, and I know how to use _.map or _.filter, e.g.

```
var newArray = _.map(myArray, function(item) {
  return item.type === 'beta';
});
```

but those return the whole object. I suspect I can get what I want with chaining, but I'm not figuring out how I can do this.

Thanks.

Comment: What form do you want the result in? Array of strings?

Comment: @SMcCrohan Yes, that would be the desired result.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with the native [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). It'd look like this (using ES6 fat-arrow functions for conciseness):

```
myArray.filter(item => item.type === 'beta').map(item => item.name)
```

The ES5 form is:

```
myArray.filter(function(item) {return item.type === 'beta'})
     .map(function(item) {return item.name})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a lodash solution that uses [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) and [filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter).

```
var result = _(myArray).filter({ type: 'beta' }).map('name').value();
```

```js
var myArray = [
  {
    name: 'Person 1',
    type: 'alpha'
  },
  {
    name: 'Person 2',
    type: 'beta'
  },
  {
    name: 'Person 3',
    type: 'gamma'
  },
  {
    name: 'Person 4',
    type: 'beta'
  },
  {
    name: 'Person 5',
    type: 'gamma'
  },
];

var result = _(myArray).filter({ type: 'beta' }).map('name').value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Dang, I thought I tried that. I must have just been off by a couple characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` method to return the items of type `'beta'`, then use the `map` method to return only the `item.name` of each object:

```
myArray.
   filter(function(item){ return item.type === 'beta'; }).
   map(function(item){ return item.name; });
```

Answer (score 1):

ES6 with parameter destructuring:

```
myArray.filter(({type}) => type === 'beta').map(({name}) => name)
```